# How to watch a Gmail mailbox for new messages with Ruby

Tags: ruby, gmail, gmail-api, google-api-client

So, I'm trying to build a small app that will listen for new messages on a Gmail mailbox and do stuff with the new messages it receives.

I have the following code that connects to the Gmail API watches a user mailbox:

```
require 'google/apis/gmail_v1'
require 'googleauth'
require 'googleauth/stores/file_token_store'
require 'fileutils'

OOB_URI = 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Gmail API Ruby Quickstart'
CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH = 'client_secret.json'
CREDENTIALS_PATH = File.join(Dir.home, '.credentials',
                             "gmail-ruby-quickstart.yaml")
SCOPE = Google::Apis::GmailV1::AUTH_GMAIL_MODIFY

##
# Ensure valid credentials, either by restoring from the saved credentials
# files or initiating an OAuth2 authorization. If authorization is required,
# the user's default browser will be launched to approve the request.
#
# @return [Google::Auth::UserRefreshCredentials] OAuth2 credentials
def authorize
  FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(CREDENTIALS_PATH))

  client_id = Google::Auth::ClientId.from_file(CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH)
  token_store = Google::Auth::Stores::FileTokenStore.new(file: CREDENTIALS_PATH)
  authorizer = Google::Auth::UserAuthorizer.new(
      client_id, SCOPE, token_store)
  user_id = 'default'
  credentials = authorizer.get_credentials(user_id)
  if credentials.nil?
    url = authorizer.get_authorization_url(
        base_url: OOB_URI)
    puts "Open the following URL in the browser and enter the " +
             "resulting code after authorization"
    puts url
    code = gets
    credentials = authorizer.get_and_store_credentials_from_code(
        user_id: user_id, code: code, base_url: OOB_URI)
  end
  credentials
end

# Initialize the API
service = Google::Apis::GmailV1::GmailService.new
service.client_options.application_name = APPLICATION_NAME
service.authorization = authorize

watch_request = Google::Apis::GmailV1::WatchRequest.new
watch_request.topic_name= 'projects/my-project/topics/push'
service.watch_user('me', watch_request)
```

What I can't work out is how I actually get notified of new messages. Can anyone help?

Pages I've read to get this far:

- https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/about-auth
- https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/watch
- https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push

## Update: 25/03/2016

So, inspecting the `google-api-client` gem code, I worked out that I need to provide a block to the `watch_user` method. I tried that, but the resulting object doesn't seem to provide any methods of handling events for new messages:

```
#...
service.watch_user('me', watch_request) do |request|
  puts request.inspect
  puts request.methods
end
```

`inspect` yields:

```
#<Google::Apis::GmailV1::WatchResponse:0x007fecd515f9e0 @expiration="1459518159351", @history_id="1038029">
```

`methods` yields:

```
expiration
expiration=
history_id
history_id=
update!
to_json
to_h
psych_to_yaml
to_yaml
to_yaml_properties
pretty_print
pretty_print_cycle
pretty_print_instance_variables
pretty_print_inspect
nil?
===
=~
!~
eql?
hash
<=>
class
singleton_class
clone
dup
itself
taint
tainted?
untaint
untrust
untrusted?
trust
freeze
frozen?
to_s
inspect
methods
singleton_methods
protected_methods
private_methods
public_methods
instance_variables
instance_variable_get
instance_variable_set
instance_variable_defined?
remove_instance_variable
instance_of?
kind_of?
is_a?
tap
send
public_send
respond_to?
extend
display
method
public_method
singleton_method
define_singleton_method
object_id
to_enum
enum_for
gem
pretty_inspect
==
equal?
!
!=
instance_eval
instance_exec
__send__
__id__
```

Here's a link to the gem's code on GitHub: https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client

Comment: FWIW: have you checked out the [`gmail`](https://github.com/gmailgem/gmail) gem?  Seems like you could use that and poll to see if the `inbox.count` has incremented.

Comment: The old IMAP method works well. The new Google API for Email may have more limitations.

Comment: @orde @tadman Thanks, but I want to work out how to use the `watch` method that the Gmail API provides: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/watch

Comment: Late comment, but see here for how to set up webhooks to receive push notifications in your app: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push